# Clear the text in multiple TextBox's at once

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application with a `Grid` where there are multiple `TextBox`s. How I can make every `TextBox.Text = null;` with a button click?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (UIElement control in myGrid.Children)
        {
            if (control.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
            {
                TextBox txtBox = (TextBox)control;
                txtBox.Text = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Strange way to determine the type. What if I have a type called `MyNamespace.TextBox`? :-)

Comment: Ok, so last comment would be to follow [CA1800](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182271.aspx) even though your code is a bit diff.

Comment: A better way to do this would be to use the `OfType` Linq method: `foreach(TextBox tb in myGrid.Children.OfType<TextBox>()) { }`.  Or, use the `as` operator, instead of comparing types directly, since it supports inheritance: `var controlAsTextBox = control as TextBox;  if (controlAsTextBox != null) { }`.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this would work:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    foreach (UIElement element in this.grid.Children) {
        TextBox textBox = element as TextBox;
        if (textBox == null)
            continue;

        textBox.Text = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also use the Linq method, `OfType`: `forech(TextBox tb in grid.Children.OfType<TextBox>()) { }`.

Answer (score 1):

The code Tom and CodeNaked gave will do what you want, but I would *generally* advise against this logic.

The Grid is there to help you organize your controls **visually**, it's a **layout container**. By no means it should be used to organize your controls **logically**, behind the scenes.

As I said, though, this is quite general advise. Your program might benefit from the other approach.

Comment: +1 I agree with you completely, but still wanted to answer the question

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple approaches to this problem.

The first is a hybrid approach where you would have the data flow down to your text boxes through bindings and a button click remove the data.

To start with you need to make sure your data classes implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx):

```cs
public class Foo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string bar;
    private string baz;

    public string Bar
    {
        get { return this.bar; }
        set
        {
            this.bar = value;

            // this is where the magic of bindings happens
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Bar");
        }
    }

    // rest of the class here...
}
```

Referenced in your XAML through bindings:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!-- ... -->
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0"
             Text="{Binding Bar}" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1"
             Text="{Binding Baz}" />

    <!-- A more complete example would use Button.Command -->
    <Button Grid.Row="2"
            Content="CLEAR"
            Click="ClearButton_Click" />
```

Finally, these bindings are wired up using the `DataContext` and a routed event handler in your `Window`s code-behind:

```cs
public Window1()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    // sets up the DataContext used by the bindings
    this.Clear();
}

private void ClearButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Clear();
}

private void Clear()
{
    this.DataContext = new Foo();
}
```

This approach will push you in a better direction to handle more complicated UI's.

---

A last ditch effort would be:

```cs
/// <summary>This is a bad choice.</summary>
private void ClearButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // assumes the Grid is named MyGrid
    foreach (var textBox in this.MyGrid.Children.OfType<TextBox>())
    {
        textBox.Text = null;
    }
}
```